# Filtering an associative array find largest values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an associative array containing results from a form, I need to have this ordered by the largest value first and then descending, or even just be able to print to the page the items in descending order.

```
var results = {
  [title1, 5],
  [title2, 8],
  [title3, 2],
  [title4, 9],
  [title5, 1]
}
```

I am currently creating 'results' by grabbing values from a form and storing them in this array. I can grab the max value using Array.max, but that is it. I don't know how I would go about ordering this or spitting out the items in descending order. I have thought about each time I find the max, them printing this and removing the object but I wondered if there was a more efficient way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no own effort of solving the problem whatsoever.

Comment: Hint: Loop through and compare

Comment: @CBroe There's a close reason for that already. "Off-topic" -> "*Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your code does not show valid JavaScript. You mean one of two things (abbreviated):

```
var results = { title1: 5, title2: 8 };
```

...or...

```
var results = [ ['title1', 5], ['title2', 8] ];
```

Assuming you mean the second, you can find the largest by sorting the array using a custom comparator:

```
results.sort(function(a,b) { return a[1] < b[1]; });
```

The largest item will be in the first index of the array after sorting.

```
var largest = results[0];
```